# Ubuntu 12.04 stopped suddenly to recognize all usb storage.

Tags: 12.04, usb, usb-drive

Storage gets listed in `lsub` but is not mounted by nautilus.  I tried 2 different devices: a usb stick and an external HDD. usb mouse on same port works fine. is there anyway to force mount it?

my /etc/fstab file,

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0 
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation 
UUID=f1fd50a1-7a61-413c-9332-4bf94cb3321c / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation 
UUID=4d1ab5a9-4477-4222-b6d0-cdc5818fc55e none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: what `dmsg` shows?

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab` what it shows?

Comment: what do you mean "dmsg"?

Comment: cat/etc/fstab shows: 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=f1fd50a1-7a61-413c-9332-4bf94cb3321c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=4d1ab5a9-4477-4222-b6d0-cdc5818fc55e none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: run `dmesg` and give output. use pastebin.com to paste and provide link to your paste.

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.com/sVxEt5pf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why Nautilus isn't showing the drives. It looks like they're showing up as **sdb**, so you can attempt to force mount the partitions by using **sdb1**, **sdb2**, etc. Assuming you're mounting the first partition, first make a folder somewhere (I'll use /mnt/sdb1 for this example), then run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

Then cd into /mnt/sdb1 and see if the files are showing up. Any error you get will help you diagnose the real problem. I would normally guess here that the filesystem might be corrupt, but that's unlikely to be true for two separate drives.

Comment: Also, Nautilus usually tries to mount the drives somewhere in /media; you might check there and see if maybe it's just not showing up in the file manager. It'll be either /media/[Drive Label] or /media/[UUID] by default, I think.

Comment: It worked and mounted the drive with this error message: eli@eli-Latitude-E6420:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.

Comment: after un-mounting and re-inserting the drive to the usb port- nautilus still does not mount it automatically. it does not apear in /media either. I mounted it again using the mount command and this time got no error message.

Comment: @eli Try opening terminal and running `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1`or `sudo dosfsck /dev/sdb1`. You can't paste the command into Terminal without right-clicking, so type them. Carefully. Also, ***be sure to change the device name as necessary** as fsck can, in rare cases , do weird things where you don't want them to be done.

Comment: I get this message: fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found. and for the second command: Currently, only 1 or 2 FATs are supported, not 0.