# Nautilus does not mount usb storage automatically

Tags: automount, usb-drive

devices are recognized and can be mounted using mount command (see [Ubuntu 12.04 stopped suddenly to recognize all usb storage.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142779/ubuntu-12-04-stopped-suddenly-to-recognize-all-usb-storage/142789#142789)) but are not automatically mounted.

using Ubuntu 12.04 on dell Lattitude E-6420.

Answer (score 2):

`gconf-editor` may be the wrong tool now. `dconf-editor` is the new favorite :-)
So open [dconf-editor [image: Install dconf-editor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor) and navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`, where you will find at least two entries:

- automount
- automount-open

Check the first one to mount media automatically and the second one to open a nautilus-window with the already mounted media.

You can find additional information about dconf/gconf in the answer to [Can I use dconf-editor to modify Gconf settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122039/can-i-use-dconf-editor-to-modify-gconf-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Open gconf-editor and find the following path:

```
/apps/nautilus/preferences/
```

and check the box media_automount !

or:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true
```

Comment: the media_automount field does not exist there...

Comment: Unity, gnome-shell or both give the issue??

Comment: edited my reply, try the second suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am using gnome shell. haven't checked on unity - i will check later and post  results. unfortunately your second suggestion doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Checked in Unity - does not work either. I now see media_automount in the gconf-editor (i guessed i missed it earlier), it is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

To enable or disable automount open a terminal and type dconf-editor followed by the [Enter] key.

Browse to **org.gnome.desktop.media-handling**.

The **automount** key controls whether to automatically mount media. If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically mount media such as user-visible hard disks and removable media on start-up and media insertion.

There is another key **org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount-open**. This controls whether to automatically open a folder for automounted media.

If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically open a folder when media is automounted. This only applies to media where no known x-content/* type was detected; for media where a known x-content type is detected, the user configurable action will be taken instead. This can be configured as shown below. 
Hope this helps! Quoted from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB).

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount true
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open true
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/volume_manager/automount_drives true
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/volume_manager/automount_media true
```